# Trying to call a string and list through

Tags: lambda, racket

I've defined two functions a string and a list and want to append the string to the last 3 elements of the list if the length of the list is > 4 and if it's not empty append the last character of the list to the string. I've got this so far but I'm stuck at a roadblock here

```
(define s (string #\b #\o #\a #\t))
(define L1 '(Apple Pear Banana Grape Ruler))

(define funct (λ ()
             (cond
               ((> 4) (cons s (cdr (cdr L1))))
               ((< 3) (cons (last L1) s))
               ((empty?) 0))))
```

It's my first time working with Racket and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: What's the roadblock? Or in other terms, what is the error message, or strange behavior?

Comment: no matter what I input I always get "arity mismatch" for example typing just `(funct)`
`>: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: at least 2
  given: 1
  arguments...:`
or if I put a list right after for example `(funct '1 2 3)`
It'll just return the same thing except "expected: 0, given: 3" 
I've defined the list and string and just want the function to run to return the condition answer

Answer (score 0):

Near the end of your code you have this: `(> 4)`

The `>` function takes at least two arguments.

Also, the `empty?` function takes one.

Here's an example of how to use cond with boolean-returning functions like `>` `empty?` and others:

```lisp
#lang racket

;((U Int List) -> String)
;
;Returns "hi" if the number is less than 0,
;"lol" if the number is not less than zero (aka greater than or equal to zero)
;"it's a list bro" if its a list
(define (foobar number-or-list)
  (cond ; I personally prefer using brackets in a cond. In my mind, it's easier to read,
        ; but it's the same as using parens.
        [(list? number-or-list) ; Check this first, as we can't do `<` on a list
         "it's a list bro"]
        [(< 0 number-or-list) "hi"]
        [else ; The else case is just a word instead of an expression.
              ; It's really useful if you want to have a "fallback"
         "lol"]))
```

Here's the docs for [`cond`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29), [`>`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=cond#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._%7E3e%29%29), and [`empty?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=cond#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._empty%7E3f%29%29)

Comment: @racketRe did this solve your problem? If so, please accept and or upvote this answer. If it didn't the community (and me, of course) could look into helping you further, perhaps.